# ArrayBag grab() and remove() methods, how to remove String after using .grab() method?

Tags: java, netbeans, methods

Say I want to add 3 adjectives to an ArrayBag, and by using every method in the JavaDoc for ArrayBag, what should I do to remove an adjective one at a time after use if the grab() method takes an adjective at random from the ArrayBag and uses it?

```
/**
 * Accessor method to retrieve a random element from this ArrayBag and will
 * remove the grabbed element from the ArrayBag
 *
 * @return A randomly selected element from this ArrayBag
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalStateException Indicated that the ArrayBag is
 * empty
 */
public E grab() {
    int i;
    //E n;

    if (items == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ArrayBag size is empty");
    }

    i = (int) (Math.random() * items + 1);

   // n = elementArray[i - 1];

    //if (items != 0) {
    //    remove(n);
    //}

    return elementArray[i - 1];
}
```

and

```
/**
 * Remove one specified element from this ArrayBag
 *
 * @param target The element to remove from this ArrayBag
 * @return True if the element was removed from this ArrayBag; false
 * otherwise
 */
public boolean remove(E target) {
    int i;

    if (target == null) {
        i = 0;

        while ((i < items) && (elementArray[i] != null)) {
            i++;
        }
    } else {
        i = 0;

        while ((i < items) && (!target.equals(elementArray[i]))) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (i == items) {
        return false;
    } else {
        items--;
        elementArray[i] = elementArray[items];
        elementArray[items] = null;
        return true;
    }
}
```

My current code I have tried.

```
    printText(3, "adjectives");
    adjectives.ensureCapacity(3);
    adjective = input.nextLine();
    String[] arr = adjective.split(" ");
    for(String ss : arr) {
        adjectives.add(ss);
```

Once I call `adjectives.grab()` how do I go about removing that random String once it has been used? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies within changing the size of the ArrayBag after removing the element from the ArrayBag all within the grab() method.

```
/**
 * Accessor method to retrieve a random element from this ArrayBag and will
 * remove the grabbed element from the ArrayBag
 *
 * @return A randomly selected element from this ArrayBag
 * @throws java.lang.IllegalStateException Indicated that the ArrayBag is
 * empty
 */
public E grab() {
    int i;
    E n;

    if (items == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("ArrayBag size is empty");
    }

    i = (int) (Math.random() * items + 1);

    n = elementArray[i - 1];

    remove(n);

    trimToSize();

    return n
}
```